# Web2py UnpicklingError

Tags: web2py

Am getting this web2py error in Ubuntu:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mwk/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/mwk/web2py/applications/britamintell/models/db2.py", line 15, in <module>
    auth.signature)
  File "/home/mwk/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 834, in define_table
    table = self.lazy_define_table(tablename,*fields,**args)
  File "/home/mwk/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 873, in lazy_define_table
    polymodel=polymodel)
  File "/home/mwk/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 500, in create_table
    sql_fields_old = pickle.load(tfile)
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '�'.
```

what is this and how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no much information about what where you trying to do. But, I imagine that you are trying to migrate a database.
If you are using MYSQL as your BBDD backend you can try change the length to"length=255" on your string fields.

Also it seems that a strange caracter is beeing used in a table/field name

Comment: Hi, I realized that one of my databases was corrupted. I got a backup copy and replaced and it worked. Regards